Porque no puedo instalar ningun plugin en atom?
Entro en la opción de instalar los paquetes. Busco el paquete por su nombre como emmet por ejemplo y no me aparece ningún paquete para poder instalar

Atom fue descontinuado el 15 de diciembre de 2022 Sunsetting Atom - The GitHub Blog
